# How to check marker with same geo coordinates already exists in Google maps v2? Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app in which first time when app starts it fetch all the locations in terms of latitude and longitude from my server and show them on the map in terms of markers. After that my app starts receiving coordinates through pushing mechanism for which i implement Google Cloud Messaging GCM. So now what i want the coordinate which my app receive through GCM it first check whether the marker with same latitude and longitude already present on the map or not if yes then remove that marker from the map. Please guide me how can i achieve this.

Here is my code when first time my app start and fetch coordinates from the server through service.

```
user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GPS);
             String Latitude, Longitude, Type;
             LatLng latLngGps;         
             int a=user.length();
             for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
             JSONObject c=user.getJSONObject(i);
             Latitude=c.getString(TAG_LAT);
             Longitude=c.getString(TAG_LONG);           
             ID=c.getString(TAG_ID);
mGoogleMap .addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLngGps).title("A").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red)));
}
```

And this is how i am getting coordinate through GCM

```
json = new JSONObject(message);
            String lat = json.getString("lati");
            String lon = json.getString("longi");

                Double l1,l2;

                l1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                l2 = Double.parseDouble(lon);





LatLng newLatLong = new LatLng(l1, l2);



//Here i want to check where marker with same position already present on map or not if yes delete that maker otherwise plot a marker on map



 LatLng newLatLong = new LatLng(l1, l2);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLong)
                              .title("GCM"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply build a `Set<LatLng>` and store the initial marker locations there. Then, when you receive new locations via GCM, just check if your set already contains `newLatLong`. If so, you can delete it, otherwise create the marker for the map and also add the `newLatLong` to your set.

However, and depending on your data sources, you probably might end with LatLngs that are "almost" equal but not quite. If that's an issue, instead of simply checking if set "contains" the new LatLng, you may want to do some more sophisticated checks whether the new LatLng is "almost equal" to any of the LatLngs in the Set.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the marker like this,`Marker m1;`

```
m1 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLong)
                          .title("GCM"));
```

then check it's visible or not marker,

```
if(m1.isvisible())
{
  //do something
}
```

get position by marker , use like this

```
LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
```

//compare the latitude and longitude value and add the marker before you check the position values

```
for(int i=0;i<arr_lat.size();i++)
{ 
   if(arr_lat.get(i) == lat_value)
     if(arr_lng.get(i) == lng_value)
        //same values don't add the marker and remove marker.
   else
      //add the lat_value and lng_value positon in arraylist ,add the marker in map

}
```

Comment: i want to check/compare coordinate which i receive from GCM with the position of already present markers on the map. I don't think so Isvisible() can complete my requirement.

Comment: I think.. if you set all marker at a Variable.. then you can get 'check/compare' status of marker.

Comment: you just add the latlng values in arraylist , check/compare the position and if it's available remove the marker or not add the marker